# OSError: cannot identify image file (issue with certain images)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a script that is downloading and performing certain operations on files from a website. A couple of times a week some of the images will throw this error (edit for bump):

`OSError: cannot identify image file '57343948435235236aede7dceb672559.png'`

Even when manually running code as simple as the following, it produces the error:

`imagefile = Image.open('57343948435235236aede7dceb672559.png')`

Here are the important facts:

- If I redownload the file using `requests.get()` I get the same error when attempting to open it.
- If I redownload the file by saving it using a web browser, I instead get the error `PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file` when attempting to open it using PIL
- I can view the files (using Window Photo Viewer, a Linux image viewer, etc.) so they aren't completely corrupted.
- If I open the image in Paint and save it under the same name, I can then open it using PIL.

Given all this, it *appears* to be an issue with specific image files hosted on the site; they are viewable in applications, but not openable using PIL. I'm assuming something is wrong with the byte structure or headers in the image, and saving overwrites those issues. **Is there some library or automatic process I can use to 'fix' these images when the error occurs?**

Below, I am including a minimal, reproducible example. **PLEASE NOTE: THE EXAMPLE URL IN THIS CASE IS NSFW IN NATURE, AND THEREFORE HAS BEEN REDACTED. SEE MY COMMENT TO THIS POST FOR A PASTEBIN LINK TO THE FULL CODE.**

```
from PIL import Image

url = 'SEE ABOVE NOTE'
file_name =(url).split('/')[-1:][0]

# Downloading the image file data.
file_data = get(url).content

# Write the data to a file.
with open(file_name, 'wb+') as file_object:
    file_object.write(file_data)

# Opening the image with PIL
with Image.open(file_name) as image_file:
    # "OSError: cannot identify image file" happens here
    pass
```

Comment: Please provide one or two of those files. Otherwise, it's kind of impossible for people here to help investigating that issue. Also, please provide a [mre]. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67916256/edit) at any time.

Comment: what does file 57343948435235236aede7dceb672559.png says ?

Comment: @HansHirse I have included a minimal reproducible example, however due to the content nature of the URL, it has not been included. I have uploaded the example (with URL) here to accurately reproduce the issue: https://pastebin.com/kZEUXb90